# Python Yaml dump remove Extra junk

Tags: python, yaml

I created a dictionary of sets:

```
db = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(set))
```

iterated through a db and added what I needed from the rows

```
db['greenhouse1']['fruits'].append('apples')  
db['greenhouse1']['fruits'].append('oranges')
db['greenhouse1']['colors'] = ["red", "orange"]

db['greenhouse2']['fruits'].append('banana')
```

the `yaml.dump(db)`
adds a bunch of crap I don't want:

```
greenhouse1: !!python/object/apply:collections.defaultdict
  args:
    - *d001
  dictitems:
    fruits:
    - oranges
    - apples
    colors:
    - orange
    - red
```

args I don't want and dictitems I don't want just the depth below that

Answer (score 1):

There is all kind of weird things going on. E.g. you cannot append to a `set` as you claim
from your code. Are you sure you didn't specify `list` as argument to the nested `defaultdict`?

In any case your "junk" is caused by `PyYAML`'s way of dumping complex objects, instead of normal
dicts.

What I recommend is using `ruamel.yaml` instead as it handles YAML 1.2 (which replaced YAML 1.1, which
is what PyYAML partly supports, back in 2009), its `dump` by default handles `utf-8` and
can work with `Path` instances in addition to opened files.

Just make a representer for `defaultdict` that does away with the `defaultdict`-ness:

```py
import sys
from collections import defaultdict
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

outfile = Path('db.yaml')

db = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

db['greenhouse1']['fruits'].append('apples')  
db['greenhouse1']['fruits'].append('oranges')
db['greenhouse1']['colors'] = ["red", "orange"]

db['greenhouse2']['fruits'].append('banana')


def default_dict_to_yaml(representer, data):
    return representer.represent_dict(dict(data.items()))

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
# yaml.indent(mapping=4, sequence=4, offset=2)
yaml.Representer.add_representer(defaultdict, default_dict_to_yaml)
yaml.dump(db, outfile)

print(outfile.read_text())
```

Which shows your `db.yaml` contains:

```
greenhouse1:
  fruits:
  - apples
  - oranges
  colors:
  - red
  - orange
greenhouse2:
  fruits:
  - banana
```

Without first having to write to a JSON file.

Of course this (and your solution) doesn't load back to a `defaultdict`.
If you want that instead you should look at [this
answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52954451/1307905), but
it will get you some "junk" so Python knows what to default to in the loaded `defaultdict`.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled on a weird solution. Basically dump to json, load json and update the object then dump yaml

```
if path.exists("db.json") == True:
    with open("db.json", 'r') as j:
        old_db = json.load(j)
        db.update(old_db)

with open("db.json", 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(json.dumps(db))

if path.exists("db.json") == True:
    with open("db.json", 'r') as j:
        old_db = json.load(j)
        db.update(old_db)
with open("db.yaml", 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(yaml.dump(db, default_flow_style=False))
```

I do not understand why dumping and loading would make this work, but it works.

Comment: Is there any reason to first dump the stream to a string, then write the string to a stream? It is much more efficient to make the last line `yaml.dump(db, outfile, default_flow_style=false))`.  Same for dumping JSON: use `json.dump(db, outfile)`.